# rails before_create not called when creating an object with Object.const_get().new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I have a single table inheritance mechanism and a controller method that creates objects based on a text type.

From my controller:

```
tile = Object.const_get(tile_data[:type]).new(params_from_tile(tile_data))

tile.save
```

inside my model base class I have several before create hooks:

```
before_create :set_handle, :upload
```

It appears none of my hooks are firing, does it have something to do with my use of Object.const_get to create my objects?

Edit: I've managed to work around this by not using Object.const_get().new now I'm just invoking my Tile.new directly, and there does not appear to be any negative repercussions, so yeah.

Comment: Your code is not *creating* records but only *initializing* it, therefore your `before_create` callbacks are not executed. Use `.create(...)` instead of `.new()` OR use `after_initialize` callback

Comment: Sorry, I omitted that part, I am calling .save

Comment: Try raising an error in either `set_handle` or `upload` and see if that error is raised or not. This way you will be sure if these callbacks are triggered or not.

Comment: I think I've answered my own question, not using Object.const_get().new fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed this to invoke the baseclass directly:

```
Tile.new(params_from_tile(tile_data))
```

And now my hooks are being called as expected, so I'm not sure why this behaves this way, and would appreciate a better answer from someone who knows, but it appears that the answer is that using Object.const_get().new to create an object skips all hooks. On a side note, Invoking create on the baseclass with just a type attribute will still cause subclass hooks to fire, So thats nice.

Comment: That's weird. A const is a const. Shouldn't matter how you get it. If you could prepare an example rails app that demonstrates the problem, I'd tell you why it happens :)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, there is no difference how you access the class, both of these would behave exactly same:

```
Tile.new(params_from_tile(tile_data))
```

and

```
Object.const_get("Tile").new(params_from_tile(tile_data))
```

Your seeing bad behaviour may have to do with some other small thing missing.

May be `tile_data[:type]` in your example pointing to something else, did you make sure `Tile` record gets saved without `callback`. Can you try with `Object.const_get("Tile")` and see what happens.